# How to specify a path when extracting data from Amplitude to s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, amplitude

I have a destinaion for export events of Amplitude.

I want to save the extracted event data like my_bucket_name/amplitude/2023/10/16/.(my_bucket_name/amplitude/YYYY/MM/DD/HH)
However, the actual saved format is my_bucket_name/amplitude/{{projectID}}/{{fileName}}
How Can I specify the storage path?

My destination is as follows.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylcak.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlCip.png)